# TwitterKit 3.0.3 Failed authorization

Tags: twitter, swift3, twitterkit

I used this official [Guide](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/log-in-with-twitter#redirect) from Twitter for Log In

My steps:

1. **Callback URL** leave field blank in Application Management
2. Install pods `pod 'Fabric'`, `pod 'TwitterKit'`
3. Add on **Info.plist**

> ```
> <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
> <array>
>     <dict>
>         <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
>         <array>
>             <string>twitterkit-xxxxxxxx</string>
>             <string>fbxxxxxxxx</string>
>         </array>             
>     </dict>
> </array>
> <key>FacebookAppID</key>
> <string>xxxxx</string>
> <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
> <string>Name</string>    
> <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
> <array>
>     <string>twitter</string>
>     <string>twitterauth</string>
>     <string>fbapi</string>
>     <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
>     <string>fbauth2</string>
>     <string>fbshareextension</string>
> </array>
> <key>Fabric</key>
> <dict>
>   <key>APIKey</key>
>   <string>xxxxxxxxxx</string>         
>   <key>Kits</key>
>   <array>
>       <dict>
>           <key>KitInfo</key>
>           <dict/>
>           <key>KitName</key>
>           <string>Crashlytics</string> 
>      </dict>
> </array>
> </dict>
> ```

3. Add on `class AppDelegate`

   ```
   import TwitterKit
   ....
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       ....
       Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"xxxxxx", consumerSecret:"xxxxx") 
   }
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {    
       return Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
   }
   ```
4. Add Frameworks:
   [image]
5. Add on `Header.h` `#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>`
6. Add **TwitterLogInButton** from official [Guide](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/log-in-with-twitter#redirect)

When I click the button to log in, I get an error (test was conducted on a Simulator iOS 9.3):

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "twitterauth://authorize?consumer_key=xxxSAMExxx&consumer_secret=yyyyyyy&oauth_callback=twitterkit-xxxSAMExxx" - error: "(null)"
[TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Error obtaining user auth token.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=-1 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
  <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash>
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
  <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash>
}
```

Comment: Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: addding callback url would solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the CFBundleURLSchemes entries separate like below:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbXXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>twitterkit-XXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

You might also want to migrate from Fabric as presented in the [official Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/fabric)

Comment: I had this setting, but still failed